# nodejs, edit profile, password. Mongoose and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The problem is it does not change value of graduated when req.body.password is empty. However graduated should also changed although req.body.password is empty. But password should not change when req.body.password and at same time graduated value should be updated. So value of graduated is not changed when user didn't change password and leave it as a blank.  Any suggestion?

```
router.post('/edit', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$set:{

        email: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        classc: req.body.classc,
        major: req.body.major,
        minor: req.body.mino,
        linkedin: req.body.linkedin,
        bio: req.body.bio
}
 },{ new: true }, function (err, user, done){

        if (err) {
          return err;
        } 

        else {

            if (typeof req.body.graduated == 'undefined') {
               user.graduated = false;


            } else if (typeof req.body.graduated == 'string') {
                user.graduated = true;

            }

          if (req.body.password) {
            user.password = req.body.password;
            user.save()
          } else {

          }

        }
        res.redirect('/profile');
    });
```

This is my pre update function

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {      
    console.log                                                                                                                                  
    if(this.password){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        this.password  = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8),null);                                                                                                             
    }



    next()                                                                                                                                                                     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the values password and graduated saved independently of each other, have the `user.save()` command after both checks, and not inside one of them.

```
if (err) {
    return err;
} 

else {
    if (typeof req.body.graduated == 'undefined') {
       user.graduated = false;
    } else if (typeof req.body.graduated == 'string') {
        user.graduated = true;
    }

    if (req.body.password && req.body.password !== "") {
        user.password = req.body.password;
    } else {

    }

    user.save()
}
res.redirect('/profile');
```

Comment: Hi, graduated also has to change when password is undefined...  My code works exactly same as your code I think. But graduate always has to change even req.body.password is empty

Comment: Hey, @ScottKim! I just edited my answer. Does that solve it?

Comment: Hello, In this case , its save password as empty string "",

Comment: That's probably because the field is coming as an empty string in the request. You could modify your password check to verify if that's the case as well: `if (req.body.password && req.body.password !== ""){...}`